# Unable to reproduce CoreFoundation CFSetRemoveAllValues

Tags: ios

I am Getting CoreFoundation CFSetRemoveAllValues and crash report as following on crashlytics. Seems like this crash never appeared before, because could not find any solution. Can anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance!

```
Crashed: Thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a16cf8 CFSetRemoveAllValues + 52
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a0dff0 __CFRunLoopKillOneTimer + 36
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b59aa1e0 CFArrayApplyFunction + 80
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a0dfb0 __CFRunLoopDeallocateTimers + 64
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a16888 __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke + 24
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5ab10fc CFBasicHashApply + 132
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a16864 CFSetApplyFunction + 172
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a07784 __CFRunLoopDeallocate + 212
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1b5a10290 _CFRelease + 224
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1b59f5a08 __CFTSDFinalize + 124
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b57a9f8c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 580
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b57a6df4 _pthread_exit + 80
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b57a7e64 _pthread_wqthread_legacy_worker_wrap + 94
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b57a7c04 _pthread_wqthread + 416
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b57aa740 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Got the same crash. Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: We got the same crash. Does anyone have the solution or at least reason why this happened?